# Why does the entry widget not work in this case i put it in a frame, tkinter-python

Tags: python, tkinter

So this is a basic clock and alarm that i am creating, and in the process i want the user to type in what hour and minute they want to set for the alarm. But the entry widget here is not responding.

```
import time 
import tkinter as tk


current_date, current_time = 0, 0
def current_info(timeinfo): #function to get the current time and date
    global current_date, current_time
    # current time
    current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    current_date = time.strftime(r'%m/%d/%Y')
    clock.after(200, timeinfo)

#Initialise the window
clock = tk.Tk()
clock.title('Easy CLock')
clock.configure(bg='#121212')
clock.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
clock.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
clock.columnconfigure(2, weight = 1)
clock.columnconfigure(3, weight = 1)


border_effects = {
    "flat": tk.FLAT,
    "sunken": tk.SUNKEN,
    "raised": tk.RAISED,
    "groove": tk.GROOVE,
    "ridge": tk.RIDGE,
}

#Logo will be under the main parent
logo = tk.PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\User\VSC\Alarm\Logo1.png')
logo_size = logo.subsample(5)

#Time and Date function
def time_date():
    current_info(time_date)
    #Displays the time
    c_time = tk.Label(f_time, text = current_time, fg='white', bg='#121212', font=('Verdana', 30))
    c_date = tk.Label(f_time, text = current_date, font=('Verdana', 10), fg='white', bg='#121212')
    c_time.grid(column=0, row=0)
    c_date.grid(column=0, row=1)

   
#alarm button command
def alarm_func(): 
    current_info(alarm_func)
    c_time = tk.Label(f_alarm, text = current_time, fg='white', bg='#121212', font=('Verdana', 10))
    c_date = tk.Label(f_alarm, text = current_date, font=('Verdana', 10), fg='white', bg='#121212')
   
    def pressed_enter(): #Command for the enter button
        set_label = tk.Label(f_alarm, text = f'Alarm has been set for {time_set}', fg ='white', bg = '#121212', borderwidth = 1, relief = border_effects['sunken'])
        set_label.grid(column = 4, row = 0, sticky = 'W')
       
    # Set the time and date for the alarm
    set_time = tk.StringVar()
    alarm_entry = tk.Entry(clock, textvariable = set_time)
    set_time.set('H : M')
    time_set = alarm_entry.get()
    
    #label and entry to set alarm / Enter Button
    c_label = tk.Label(f_alarm, text = 'Set Alarm: ', font = ('Verdana', 10), fg= 'white', bg ='#121212' )
    alarm_enter = tk.Button(f_alarm, text = 'Enter', font = ('Verdana', 7),  width = 5, command = pressed_enter)

    #Pack the widgets
    c_time.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    c_date.grid(column = 1 , row = 0)
    alarm_enter.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
    c_label.grid(row = 2, sticky = 'W')
    alarm_entry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    

    #configure the empty columns
    f_alarm.columnconfigure(2, minsize = 10)

def recall_frame(event):
    if event == f_alarm:
        event.grid_forget()
        f_time.grid(column=0, row =1, columnspan = 4, sticky = 'N')
    elif event == f_time:
        event.grid_forget()
        f_alarm.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan = 4, sticky = 'W')

def back_func():
    pass

#Creating Frames
f_time = tk.Frame(clock)  #Clock Button
f_alarm = tk.Frame(clock) #Alarm Buttton

#configure the frames
f_time.configure(bg = '#121212')
f_alarm.configure(bg = '#121212')

#Setting label in the frame
f_lbl = tk.Label(clock, text= ' Simplistic Clock', image = logo_size, font=('Verdana', 30), fg='white', bg='#121212', compound = tk.LEFT, padx = 35) 
time_but = tk.Button(clock, text='Clock', command= lambda :[time_date(), recall_frame(f_alarm)], bg='#f39c12', relief = border_effects['ridge'], pady = 7)
alarm_but = tk.Button(clock, text = 'Alarm', command = lambda :[alarm_func(), recall_frame(f_time)], bg='#f39c12', relief = border_effects['ridge'], pady = 7)
quit_but = tk.Button(clock, text='Exit', command = clock.quit, bg='#f39c12', relief = border_effects['ridge'], pady = 7)
back_but = tk.Button(clock, text = 'Back ', command = back_func, bg='#f39c12', relief = border_effects['ridge'], pady = 7)

f_lbl.config(borderwidth = 4, relief = border_effects['sunken'])

#Putting it on the frames
f_lbl.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = 'EW')
time_but.grid(column = 0, row = 3, sticky = 'EW')
alarm_but.grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky = 'EW')
quit_but.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = 'EW')
back_but.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = 'EW')

clock.mainloop()
```

i tried testing an entry widget outside the frame and the entry widget was able to work, is it because the frame f_alarm is not looping constantly in the background?

Comment: You created an Entry, set its contents to `'H : M'`, and then *immediately* called `.get()` on it.  What results are you imagining that you could possibly receive, other than `'H : M'`?  It looks like you're creating a new set of widgets 5 times per second, so anything that the user did manage to type into that Entry would soon be overlaid by a new Entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone clicks on your button which activates the `pressed_enter()` function, it will call that function again every time which will set the time to H:M and it will get that value as the `set_time.get()` is called immediately after.

You're also creating a new Entry every time the button is being clicked because you put     `alarm_entry = tk.Entry(clock, textvariable=set_time)`
in there as well. You should only  put the `set_time.get` inside of that button so that it gets the value that is currently filled in into the Entry. The other things like

```
set_time = tk.StringVar()
alarm_entry = tk.Entry(clock, textvariable=set_time)
set_time.set('H : M')
```

Should be put outside of that function so they don't get called every time someone clicks on the button.